# Filtering DAX to another table using current row's value

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I have three tables, one a standard date table and two children tables, one budget and one forecast.  I am using power pivot and would like to have a listing of the years / months across the top, and multiple brands going down the rows with the forecast and budget displayed in the grid.  When I create the measure on the forecast table to sum the budget, it sums it correctly down to the month but when I view the pivot table, I get the summed value across all brands instead of filtering to the current row's brand:

```
    2017    
    October 
Row Labels  forecast    Budget
Brand A $950,000.15         ($3,884,649.00)
Brand B $3,500,000.00       ($3,884,649.00)
Brand C $1,650,000.00       ($3,884,649.00)
Brand D $980,000.00         ($3,884,649.00)
Brand E $100,000.00         ($3,884,649.00)
Brand F $183,465.00         ($3,884,649.00)
Grand Total $7,363,465.15   ($3,884,649.00)
```

My DAX formula looks like this:

```
Budget:=CALCULATE(Sum(Budget[SummedAmount]), values(Budget[Brand Code])= ForecastEntries[Brand Code])
```

How can I get the ~3,884,649 summing just over the current brand's brand code?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve what you want is to add a dimension table `Brands` to the model which contains one row for each brand and then relate the `Budget` and `Forecast` tables to it on `[Brand Code]`.

The hard way to do it is to set up your measure like this:

```
Budget:=CALCULATE(
            SUM(Budget[SummedAmount]), 
            FILTER(
                Budget, 
                Budget[Brand Code] = 
                    IF(HASONEVALUE(Forecast[Brand Code]), 
                       VALUES(Forecast[Brand Code]), 
                       Budget[Brand Code])
            )
         )
```

The second approach quickly becomes messy as there are more dimensions.